# AttributeError: 'Moderation' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i tried to make cog for organize my bot but i have an error that i dont find how to fix. The bot successful find command in cog but when i write the command i have this error:

[image]

Could you help me pls ? Here is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import re
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    #Purge
    @commands.command()
    async def purge(ctx, amount=10):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first parameter must be `self`.

```
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    #Purge
    @commands.command()
    async def purge(self, ctx, amount=10):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add self as parameter in purge function.

async def purge(self,ctx,amount=10):
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

Comment: Thx a lot mate, have a great day